# using poi , How to set the Cell type as number

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using poi 3.6

I am able to create the excel properly. But when I trying to set the cell type as number , it always give me cell type as general.

i.e. In the newly create excel , when I right click and go to format cell ->there I always found number to be a General.

My code is like this

```
style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
dataCell.setCellValue(Float.parseFloat(value as String);
dataCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
dataCell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Can you please suggest what is missing here ?

Comment: POI 3.6 is rather old, is there a reason why you're using such an old version and not the latest one?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try this approach too:

```java
HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum());
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("0.00"));
cell.setCellStyle(style);
cell.setCellValue(Float.parseFloat("21.5"));
```

Of course, take a look at the [documentation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFDataFormat.html) and examples about [data formats](http://www.roseindia.net/java/poi/setdataformat.shtml).

Comment: Thanks a lot It is working for me I have tried 
    //style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0.0"));

but it didnt work .. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

The method you are looking for is called "setNumericCellValue" if I'm not mistaken.
Also, try setting the cell type before setting the value.

Comment: There is no method setNumericCellValue.  There is only a getNumericCellValue.  The doc for that at https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html has a reference that implies the format can be applied, but not the type.