# Limiting cells to only numeric values in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

We are using Apache POI library to create the excel sheets.

How can we restrict the cells to accept only numeric values ? Is there any class that restricts to only numbers in Apache POI library ?

Thanks
Rama Krishna

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248284/using-poi-how-to-set-the-cell-type-as-number

Comment: The example what you are referring does restriction while adding the data. But I want the user not to enter the characters in the created excel sheet. How do we restrict this at code level ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps, I should have asked my question like how to add Data Validation in Excel using Apache POI.

But here is the code to do so.

I guess this can help someone. It worked for me. You need to be careful with Cell Range.

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("SomeSheet");

Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
XSSFDataValidationHelper dvHelper = new SSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);

XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = 
    (XSSFDataValidationConstraint)
    dvHelper.createNumericConstraint(
        XSSFDataValidationConstraint.ValidationType.DECIMAL,
        XSSFDataValidationConstraint.OperatorType.BETWEEN,
        String.valueOf(Float.MIN_VALUE),
        String.valueOf(Float.MAX_VALUE)
    );

// Cell range is important here. 
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(
        0, 2, 1, 3);
// 0 - starting row, 2 - ending row
// 1 - starting col, 3 - ending col

XSSFDataValidation validation =(XSSFDataValidation)dvHelper.createValidation(
        dvConstraint, addressList);
validation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);
validation.setShowErrorBox(true);

CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
cell.setCellStyle(style);

sheet.addValidationData(validation);

cell.setCellValue(20);
```