# restricting cells to accept only alphanumeric values in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi, vba

How can we restrict the cells to accept only AlphaNumeric(A-Z,a-z,0-9) values ? Is there any class that restricts to only alphanumeric in Apache POI library ?
or is there any formula to apply  in a particular cell using Apache POI.

Thnak

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660522/limiting-cells-to-only-numeric-values-in-apache-poi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting cells to only numeric values in Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660522/limiting-cells-to-only-numeric-values-in-apache-poi)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I've posted exactly the same link

Comment: there is a difference between posting a link and marking as duplicate

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Actually it is not a duplicate. That question was about numeric values, and this is about alphanumeric ones.

Comment: it is a duplicate, because the solution is the same

Answer (score 0):

Use this excel formula to achieve this :-

*=IF(A2="",TRUE,IF(ISERROR(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1),"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))),FALSE,TRUE))*

here A2 is cell number.