# Data not getting printed in excel sheet after using formula

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to use XSSFRow to use data from one sheet to other,here is the code

```
XSSFRow r = nfrntSheet.getRow(i);
Cell c = r.createCell(7);
c.setCellFormula("'Original'!F"+(i+1)+"+'Original'!G"+(i+1)+"*-1");
```

After computing the formula the data in the written sheet will be displaced like "#value" instead of the number.
what should i do to so that original data is displayed instead of the  "#value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the cell type

```
c.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
```

so as per your code

```
XSSFRow r = nfrntSheet.getRow(i);
Cell c = r.createCell(7);
 c.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);

c.setCellFormula("'Original'!F"+(i+1)+"+'Original'!G"+(i+1)+"*-1");
```

Comment: Thx SpringLearner for the answer, But there is no change in the excel sheet

Comment: @AnandBiradar is the formula correct? did you execute the formula in the excel?

Comment: I am getting this kind for error only for numeric data and not for String values

Comment: @AnandBiradar I think you need to set the data format also check it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15248651/2664200

Comment: Thanks SpringLearner